# How to get all of listBox marked checkBox? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="637" Width="1889">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.505,0.844" Margin="0,0,0,19">
        <CheckBox x:Name="cbFilter" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="25"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbFilterMode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,410,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBlock>=</TextBlock>
            <TabItem/>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFilterValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="225,409,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1110" Height="385">
             <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="245,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="230" Width="645"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="385" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" Grid.Column="10">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="qqq"  Content="{Binding }" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var cb = sender as CheckBox;
    var item = cb.IsChecked;
    listBox.SelectedItem = item;

    if (listBox.SelectedIndex==0) return;



    string query = "SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Число Подписки] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {(";




    foreach (string i in listBox.Checked)
    {
        query += " " + i.ToString() + ".ALLMEMBERS *";
    }

    query = query.Remove(query.Length - 2);

    query += " )} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [Почта] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS";
UpdateChart(query);

}
```

It turns out only to withdraw all at once, and how to do that would be deduced by one (ie. If `checkBox == true`, then we conclude that measurement of the cube)

Comment: Could you cleanup your post to leave relevant and valid markup/code only?

Comment: could you show Model class and how do you populate your `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a such model class:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

and populating of `ListBox` looks like that:

```
    public MainWindow()//***ctor of Window
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopulateListView();
    }

    private void PopulateListView()
    {
        IList<FooClass> someValues = new List<FooClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            someValues.Add(new FooClass() { IsChecked=true});
        }
        listBox.ItemsSource = someValues;
    }
```

Then to get all `CheckBox'es` values from `ListBox` you can do:

```
    private void qqq_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var e1=listBox.Items;
        foreach (var c in listBox.ItemsSource)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((FooClass)c).IsChecked.ToString());
        }

    }
```